# Display gulp --tasks from within task

Tags: node.js, gulp

I want to dump out a message within the default gulp task to tell the user to select a task, but then list out the tasks below this message the same way which `gulp --tasks` does.

Can't seem to find anything on Google which will do this without additional plugins, which I want to avoid, if there a way?

```
exports.default = (cb) => {
    log(chalk.bgRed('Please run a task, a list has been provided below.'));
    // dump out tasks here
    cb();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to log the list of the gulp tasks, you can use `child_process` to execute `gulp --task`

```
const exec = require('child_process').execSync
exec('gulp --tasks', { stdio: 'inherit' })
```